# Getting the number of rows on MySQL with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a db with some tables like this:

```
- fruitsTable

     id       name       numberOfPeople
     1        apple      3
     2        orange     4
     3        cherry     1 

- peopleTable

     person   fruit
     john     apple
     john     orange
     john     cherry
     jack     apple
     jack     orange
     ryan     apple
     ryan     orange
     meg      orange
```

Think that peopleTable get changed everyday and consists of tens of thousands of rows.
Also, the fruitsTable has more than thousand rows.

How can I calculate the numberOfPeople column, periodically?

I am planning to set up a daily cron job which will trigger a SQL command in order to calculate the number.

Assuming that I have no experience with those JOIN commands in SQL, What kind of SQL command do I need to use without having any performance issue?

Comment: What do you mean calculate the numberOfPeople column, periodically?

Comment: @AdRock I want to print the number of people who likes cherry, orange and other stuff in one page. I thought that, in order to this, I will need a `numberOfPeople` column and I also need to update it frequently as the `peopleTable` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to change `peopleTable` table to follow structure

```
peopleTable
person fruit_id
john   1
...
```

And by the question you need follow sql

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) as count FROM fruitsTable a
LEFT JOIN peopleTable b ON a.id = b.fruit_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will output follows (Example data)

```
id  count
1   2
2   4
...
```

And update query

```
UPDATE fruitTable a SET numberOfPeople = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM peopleTable b WHERE a.id = b.fruit_id GROUP BY b.fruit_id
);
```

Comment: Do I need to put this code in a loop, or it will work for all the fruits automatically?

Comment: No, you dont need to do a loop. Untill you will set `WHERE` section in `UPDATE`. Otherwise it will update everything that in a table

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't store that field, otherwise it will be outdated very frequently if peopleTable is changed often. And simply calculate it whenever you want to show it.

But if you insist on having it, you can do:

```sql
UPDATE fruitsTable f
SET f.numberOfPeople = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM peopleTable p
    WHERE p.fruit = f.name
    )
```

If you want to get table fruits with the numberOfPeople updated everytime you do need it you would do:

```sql
SELECT f.id, f.name, COUNT(*) AS numberOfPeople
FROM fruitsTable f
INNER JOIN peopleTable p ON p.fruit = f.name
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
```

You can change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN if you have fruits that don't have any people associated with it and you still want to count them (0).

Comment: I will give a shot as soon as I reach my files on home computer.

Comment: I advise you to see the suggestion from Spell to change name to id in peopleTable. This way, if you ever change the name of a fruit, you don't have to change every occurrence of it in peopleTable.

Answer (score 0):

This will get what your asking without needing the fruitTable, doesn't depend the fruit from the peopleTable actually be in the fruitTable

```
select fruit, count(*) as 'Count' from peopleTable
group by fruit
order by fruit asc
```

The other solution I would have if both tables need to exist is the same as Filipe.